# Running single dependent class via testng.xml

Tags: testng, dependency-management

I have a very specific requirement:

**I need to run tests by not repeating/ re-writing the dependent classes in < classes > in the testing.xml**

I have researched my issue extensively and only when I didn’t find solution, I am writing this question. I hope I have provided all info needed to help me find solution.

The sample project has been added here: https://github.com/jigyasa-at-git/testngDependencyManagement/tree/master/dependencyManagement

**Setup:**

- I am using TestNG (6.13.1).
- I have huge number of classes in the suite.
- Each class contains 1 method (this is how the project needs to be set up )
- Some classes have dependencies on other classes (meaning, the methods    inside of the class have dependencies on methods in another class and    I am using “dependsOnGroups” annotation).
- I am using testing.xml for running my tests.  I am defining the dependencies inside the classes.
- This is the dependency structure in sample project:

  - Method in ClassTwo depends on method in ClassOne.
  - Method in ClassThree depends on method in ClassTwo
  - Method in ClassFour depends on method in ClassThree

**Original Testing.xml:** (this is what I want to work)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Test Dependencies">
    <test name="Test 1">
        <classes>
            <class name="ClassOne" />
            <class name="ClassTwo" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test 2">
        <classes>
            <class name="ClassThree" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test 3">
        <classes>
            <class name="ClassFour" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

**Issue:**
I am getting the following error when I run the above testing.xml:

org.testng.TestNGException: 
DependencyMap::Method "ClassThree.classThree_Test1()[pri:0, instance:ClassThree@475530b9]" depends on nonexistent group "classTwo"

On the other hand, it works if the testing.xml is updated like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Test Dependencies">
    <test name="Test 1">
        <classes>
            <class name="ClassOne" />
            <class name="ClassTwo" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test 2">
        <classes>
            <class name="ClassOne" />
            <class name="ClassTwo" />
            <class name="ClassThree" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test 3">
        <classes>
            <class name="ClassOne" />
            <class name="ClassTwo" />
            <class name="ClassThree" />
            <class name="ClassFour" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Tests run fine, but then I face another problem … those classes (ClassOne, ClassTwo and ClassThree) run multiple times since they are mentioned in all 3 < test >

I have googled (including this site) this issue a lot but am not able to find any solution. Would really appreciate any help. I am stuck badly. I need a way to resolve dependencies without making the classes to run multiple times or having to manually add them to the < classes >

Comment: `dependsOnGroups` doesn't work that way. It needs everything as a self contained unit within a `<test>` tag. You cannot have dependencies spread across multiple `<test>` tags.
If you need to ensure this kind of a dependency, then you would need to hand weave it on your own. A simple way of doing it would be to disable parallel execution, and then set attributes at the `ISuite` level wherein you keep setting some attribute, which is queried by downstream classes before executing.

Comment: Thank you for the response @KrishnanMahadevan, will you be able to provide a viable example of the solution that you are suggesting. Just googling ISuite examples is not helping me.